# Site Settings not taken into account - Browser Title, Favicon and so on

Tags: sxa

In the settings folder created by SXA, I have modified

- The browser title
- The favicon
- The Cookie Warning

But they do not display neither on CM or CD.

What should I do to make those changes effective and see the modifications ?

Comment: Did you publish? (start with settings item, if that doesn't help the homepage - I've noticed that helps sometimes)

Comment: No results publishing the item, nor the home page, nor the whole site

Comment: I submitted a support ticket with Sitecore. They recommended the accepted answer as the solution for now. Reference 8246 if you want to check for the fix in a version greater than 1.4 of SXA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now it seems obvious but it took me some time to see this.

I was not including the **Metadata Partial Design** into my pages designs.

Doing so worked well, excepted that the browser title's prefix was in between "span" tags to I used the following expression to erase all html tags inside title.

I also had to html-decode the title to show special characters

In **Views/BrowserTitle.cshtml**

```
<title>@System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@Model.Title), "<[^>]*>", "")</title>
```

Comment: As of SXA 1.7, this issue is not fixed. I reported a defect and Sitecore provided a patch. Reference number 13093.